# Tokenizing a string in XQuery outside nested bracketed expression

Tags: nested, xquery, tokenize, brackets

I'm trying to write an XQuery function to tokenize a string on a delimiter whilst ignoring delimiters inside nested bracketed expressions e.g.

```
tokenizeOutsideBrackets("1,(2,3)" , ",")         => ( "1" , "(2,3)" ) 
tokenizeOutsideBrackets("1,(2,(3,4))" , ",")     => ( "1" , "(2,(3,4))" )
tokenizeOutsideBrackets("1,(2,(3,(4,5)))" , ",") => ( "1" , "(2,(3,(4,5)))" )
tokenizeOutsideBrackets("1,(2,(3,4),5),6" , ",") => ( "1" , "(2,(3,4),5)" , "6" )
```

If I had recursive regexes or an imperative language this would be fairly trivial but I'm struggling to find a simple, easy way to do this in XQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: _"recursive regexes"_ sound like an oxymoron... It doesn't matter whether the language follows imperative or declarative paradigm, by the way.

Comment: @Alejandro: yes, I'm aware it's kind of an oxymoron... :) PCRE is what I'm usually used to and that supports recursive patterns (whether _technically_ regular or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to split first, then join tokens with unbalanced parentheses to their right hand side neighbors.

The code below will get you the desired results. It uses fn:tokenize to split, then (tail-) recursively processes the result tokens, concatenating when the preceding token has non-matching counts of "(" and ")". There are some deficiencies of this approach, namely failure to match left and right brackets properly, and treating $delimiter both as a pattern and as a literal. More coding is necessary to properly handle, however you might get the idea.

```
declare function local:tokenizeOutsideBrackets($string, $delimiter)
{
  local:joinBrackets(tokenize($string, $delimiter), $delimiter, ())
};

declare function local:joinBrackets($tokens, $delimiter, $result)
{
  if (empty($tokens)) then
    $result
  else 
    let $last := $result[last()]
    let $new-result :=
      if (string-length(translate($last, "(", "")) 
        = string-length(translate($last, ")", ""))) then
       ($result, $tokens[1])
      else
       ($result[position() < last()], concat($last, $delimiter, $tokens[1]))
    return local:joinBrackets($tokens[position() > 1], $delimiter, $new-result)
};
```

Comment: Similar to my approach but much simpler and nicer.

Answer (score 1):

This XQuery expression:

```
tokenize(replace('1,(2,(3,4),5),6','([0123456789]+|\(.*\))(,)?','$1;'),';')
```

Output:

```
1 (2,(3,4),5) 6
```

**Update**: If there is going to be strings like `'1,(2,3),(4,5),6'`, then you will need a parser for this grammar:

```
exp ::= term ( ',' term ) *

term ::= num | '(' exp ')'

num ::= ( '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' ) +
```

Comment: Nifty trick, but this fails on `'1,(2,3),(4,5),6'` which gives `1 (2,3),(4,5) 6` and not the expected `1 (2,3) (4,5) 6`

Comment: @jong: If you are going to have differents string than those provided then you will need a parser.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks for your help trying.  Was hoping I didn't have to go down the parser route but think my other solution does the job, will do some more testing.

Comment: @jong: There is no other way for this kind of grammar. By the way, functional parsers are the most easy to write following the parser combinators patterns: you just need to translate the grammar. Sadly, for Higher Order Functions in XQuery you have to wait until XQuery 3.0 Working Draft become a Recommandation.

Comment: ... or use any implementation that already implements that part of the draft (e.g. Saxon)

Comment: @jong, @Alejandro, @Pavel-Minaev: You could do this in XSLT 2.0 + FXSL 7 years ago. See my generalized LR1 parser implemented completely in XSLT 2.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

Been playing about and the function below seems to work, although I can't help thinking there's an easier way.

This code uses the functx:index-of-string function to find the indexes of all the delimiters.  It then tries each to find the first delimiter where everything to the left has an equal number of opening and closing brackets.  After this is found, this is repeated with everything to the right of this delimiter.

```
declare function local:tokenizeOutsideBrackets(
  $arg as xs:string?,
  $delimiter as xs:string) as xs:string*
{
  if (contains($arg, $delimiter))
  then
    (:find positions of all the delimiters:)
    let $delimiterPositions := (
      functx:index-of-string($arg,$delimiter),
      string-length($arg)+1 (:Add in end of string too:)
    )

    (:strip out all the fragments that have matching
      brackets to the left of each delimiter:)
    let $fragments :=
      for $endPos in $delimiterPositions
      let $candidateString := substring($arg,1,$endPos - 1)
      return
        if (local:hasMatchedBrackets($candidateString))
        then $candidateString
        else ()
    let $firstFragment := $fragments[1]
    let $endPos := string-length($firstFragment)

    (:recursively return the first matching fragment,
      plus the fragments in the remaining string:)
    return
    (
      $firstFragment,
      local:tokenizeOutsideBrackets(
        substring(
          $arg,
          $endPos+string-length($delimiter)+1,
          string-length($arg) - $endPos -(string-length($delimiter))
        ),
        $delimiter
      )
    )
  else if ($arg='') then () else ($arg)
};

declare function local:hasMatchedBrackets($arg as xs:string) as xs:boolean 
{
  count(tokenize($arg,'\(')) = count(tokenize($arg,'\)'))
};
```